# How to change a "tail" in Riggify to flex along two axis

Tags: rigging

I modeled and rigged up this dog using riggify with a basic quadruped. I have to play around with weights and things, but it mostly works fine.  The one thing that's not working is I used a "tail" for the ears and since tails only bend on one axis the ears only bend forward and backwards (Y Axis in this screenshot), but dogs ears flop to the side (X Axis).

I figured out that I can manually bend each joint of the ear by grabbing the lines across the ear, but that's tedious, considering the ears should be flopping around as the dog walks.

I found something online that suggested I select the various parts and hit "n" and then unlock the x axis and I tried that but the handle on the top still doesn't bend along that axis.

Is there something I'm missing, or some sample armatures I should use *instead* of the tail in this instance when I'm rigging my model?

[image: picture of layout]